# Sorting Version Numbers

Tags: java, sorting, version

My code below is supposed to sort version numbers into proper order. For the most part it works, but it fails a hidden test case that I don't have access to. Given that is there any edge case you can see that I might be missing.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Answer {   
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Testing 
    String[] versions = {"0.0.0","0","0.0","1.113","0.0.0.1","2.0.0","1.2","2","0.1","1.2.1","1.1.1","2.0"};
    String[] results = answer(versions);
    for(int i =0; i<results.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(results[i]);
    }   
}
public static String[] answer(String[] l) { 

    String temp = new String();
    //Insertion sort on the given array to assign correct version numbers
    for (int i = 1; i < l.length; i++) {
        for(int j = i ; j > 0 ; j--){
            if(compareVersion(l[j],l[j-1])<0){
                temp = l[j];
                l[j] = l[j-1];
                l[j-1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return l;
} 
//Will compare version numbers breaking it apart into a String array
public static int compareVersion(String version1, String version2) {
String[] arr1 = version1.split("\\.");
String[] arr2 = version2.split("\\.");

int i=0;
while(i<arr1.length || i<arr2.length){
    if(i<arr1.length && i<arr2.length){
        if(Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]) < Integer.parseInt(arr2[i])){
            return -1;
        }else if(Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]) > Integer.parseInt(arr2[i])){
            return 1;
        }
        else if(Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]) == Integer.parseInt(arr2[i]))
        {
            int result = specialCompare(version1,version2);
            if(result != 0)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
    } else if(i<arr1.length){
        if(Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]) != 0){
            return 1;
        }
    } else if(i<arr2.length){
       if(Integer.parseInt(arr2[i]) != 0){
            return -1;
        }
    }

    i++;
}

return 0;
}
  // Meant for when version numbers such as 2 and 2.0 arise. This method will make sure to
  // put the smaller version number ( in length) first
  public static int specialCompare(String str1, String str2)
 {
      String[] arr1 = str1.split("\\.");
     String[] arr2 = str2.split("\\.");
     for(int i =1; i<arr1.length;i++)
     {
        if(Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]) != 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for(int j =1; j<arr2.length;j++)
    {
        if(Integer.parseInt(arr2[j]) != 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if(arr1.length < arr2.length)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You want someone to fix something in your code but you don't even know what the failure is? How do you think anyone can accomplish this? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to clarify your question

Answer (score 6):

I read [Lukas Eder's blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/02/23/how-to-order-file-names-semantically-in-java/) in the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48946673/226513) and created a `java.util.Comparator` which orders by version (or chapter) number, based on a [JDK proposal](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2017-July/048615.html).

[`VersionNumberComparator`](https://gist.github.com/adamcbuckley/8ccae8b1ede0a65edb1756ea39bb6f2a) is defined in a GitHub gist. The follow code shows how it works.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<String> chapters = new ArrayList<>();

        chapters.add("1.1");
        chapters.add("1.2");
        chapters.add("1");
        chapters.add("1.3");
        chapters.add("1.1.1");
        chapters.add("5.6");
        chapters.add("1.1.10");
        chapters.add("4");
        chapters.add("1.1.9");
        chapters.add("1.2.1.10");
        chapters.add("2.1.1.4.5");
        chapters.add("1.2.1.9");
        chapters.add("1.2.1");
        chapters.add("2.2.2");
        chapters.add("1.2.1.11");

        System.out.println("UNSORTED: " + chapters.toString());

        chapters.sort(VersionNumberComparator.getInstance());
        System.out.println("SORTED:   " + chapters.toString());
    }
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
UNSORTED: [1.1, 1.2, 1, 1.3, 1.1.1, 5.6, 1.1.10, 4, 1.1.9, 1.2.1.10, 2.1.1.4.5, 1.2.1.9, 1.2.1, 2.2.2, 1.2.1.11]
SORTED:   [1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.9, 1.1.10, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.1.9, 1.2.1.10, 1.2.1.11, 1.3, 2.1.1.4.5, 2.2.2, 4, 5.6]
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't support the [Semantic Versioning rules of precedence](https://semver.org/).  Using the VersionNumberComparator referred to in this answer when we want `[1.0.0-alpha, 1.0.0-alpha.1, 1.0.0-alpha.beta, 1.0.0-beta, 1.0.0-beta.2, 1.0.0-beta.11, 1.0.0-rc.1, 1, 1.0, 1.0.0, 2.0.0, 2.2.0, 2.10.0]` we instead get `[1, 1.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.0-alpha, 1.0.0-alpha.1, 1.0.0-alpha.beta, 1.0.0-beta, 1.0.0-beta.2, 1.0.0-beta.11, 1.0.0-rc.1, 2.0.0, 2.2.0, 2.10.0]`

Answer (score 1):

I have recently had a need to do this in a more generic way for arbitrary file names, similar to how Windows Explorer sorts files:

[image]

[I wrote a blog post about this](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/02/23/how-to-order-file-names-semantically-in-java/). [The idea was inspired by this answer here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/37217/5314). The comparator used for ordering files this way looks like this:

```
public final class FilenameComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    private static final Pattern NUMBERS = 
        Pattern.compile("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");

    @Override 
    public final int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // Optional "NULLS LAST" semantics:
        if (o1 == null || o2 == null)
            return o1 == null ? o2 == null ? 0 : -1 : 1;
        // Splitting both input strings by the above patterns
        String[] split1 = NUMBERS.split(o1);
        String[] split2 = NUMBERS.split(o2);
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(split1.length, split2.length); i++) {
            char c1 = split1[i].charAt(0);
            char c2 = split2[i].charAt(0);
            int cmp = 0;
            // If both segments start with a digit, sort them numerically using 
            // BigInteger to stay safe
            if (c1 >= '0' && c1 <= '9' && c2 >= '0' && c2 <= '9')
                cmp = new BigInteger(split1[i]).compareTo(new BigInteger(split2[i]));
            // If we haven't sorted numerically before, or if numeric sorting yielded 
            // equality (e.g 007 and 7) then sort lexicographically
            if (cmp == 0)
                cmp = split1[i].compareTo(split2[i]);
            // Abort once some prefix has unequal ordering
            if (cmp != 0)
                return cmp;
        }
        // If we reach this, then both strings have equally ordered prefixes, but 
        // maybe one string is longer than the other (i.e. has more segments)
        return split1.length - split2.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great soluce. It may be a typo, but shouldn't be ` if (c1 >= '0' && c1 <= '9' && c2 >= '0' && c2 <= '9')` with a char '0' instead of number 0 for c2 comparison ?

Comment: Same issue as other answers: it ignore the following rule:

```When major, minor, and patch are equal, a pre-release version has lower precedence than a normal version:

Example: 1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0.```

Comment: @dankirkd: That wasn't the question here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort some versions (e.g. `0.4.3, 5.3.5, 1.2.4`) you could use my approach which includes using a [java.util.Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). To use this you have to use a sorting method (e.g. `Arrays.sort(new String[] {"0.4.3", "5.3.5", "1.2.4"}, new VersionComparator())`). The `VersionComparator` class is written below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public final class VersionComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String version1, String version2) {
        if (checkVersionFormat(version1) == false || checkVersionFormat(version2) == false) {
            System.out.println("One of the given versions uses a false format");
        }
        List<String> firstVersionElements = Arrays.asList(version1.split("\\."));
        List<String> secondVersionElements = Arrays.asList(version2.split("\\."));
        int maxVersionElements = getMaxNumber(firstVersionElements.size(), secondVersionElements.size(), 0);
        for (int counter = 0; counter < maxVersionElements; counter++) {
            if (firstVersionElements.size() == counter && secondVersionElements.size() == counter) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (firstVersionElements.size() == counter) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (secondVersionElements.size() == counter) {
                return -1;
            }
            int firstIntElement = Integer.valueOf(firstVersionElements.get(counter));
            int secondIntElement = Integer.valueOf(secondVersionElements.get(counter));
            if (firstIntElement < secondIntElement) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (firstIntElement > secondIntElement) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private boolean checkVersionFormat(String version) {
        String versionCopy = new String(version);
        String[] validChars = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "." };
        for (String character : validChars) {
            versionCopy = versionCopy.replace(character, "");
        }
        return versionCopy.equals("");
    }
    
    public static int getMaxNumber(Integer... ints) {
        int maximumInt = ints[0];
        for (int processInt : ints) {
            if (processInt > maximumInt) {
                maximumInt = processInt;
            }
        }
        return maximumInt;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comments in your code above the `specialCompare` method…

> Meant for when version numbers such as 2 and 2.0 arise. This method
>   will make sure to put the smaller version number (in length) first

So I am guessing from this that you want the version to be sorted by the length of the version number. Example: from your supplied versions string array you want to sort as below…

```
0
2
0.0
0.1
1.2
1.113
2.0
0.0.0
1.1.1
1.2.1
2.0.0
0.0.0.1
```

If this is the case, then you seem to be making this more complicated than it has to be. When you get two versions where the version lengths differ, then the one with the shorter version length should go first. So a simple check on the length of the version split arrays should solve this. If they are the same length, then you need to check each version. There is no need for a `specialCompare` method when the version lengths are the same. Simply check each version and if they are the same, then go to the next version number and so on. As soon as one version is different then you will know what to return. If you go through the whole array then you know all the version numbers are the same.

Below is a change to the `compareVersion` method using the logic above. There is no need for a  `specialCompare` method. I am guessing this is what you are looking for.

```
public static int compareVersion(String version1, String version2)
{
  String[] arr1 = version1.split("\\.");
  String[] arr2 = version2.split("\\.");

  if (arr1.length < arr2.length)
     return -1;
  if (arr1.length > arr2.length)
     return 1;

  // same number of version "." dots
  for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
  {
     if(Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]) < Integer.parseInt(arr2[i]))
       return -1;
     if(Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]) > Integer.parseInt(arr2[i]))
       return 1;
   }
   // went through all version numbers and they are all the same
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yea, turns out I figured that out just this morning and was making it harder on myself. But I appreciate you replying to my question.

Answer (score 0):

package com.e;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * Created by dpc on 17-2-27.
 * 
 */
public class VersionComparator implements Comparator {

```
@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

    if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {
        return 0;
    } else if (o1 == null && o2 != null) {
        return -1;
    } else if (o1 != null && o2 == null) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        if (o1.length() == 0 && o2.length() == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (o1.length() == 0 && o2.length() > 0) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o1.length() > 0 && o2.length() == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return compareVersion(o1, o2);
        }
    }


}


public static int compareVersion(String version1, String version2) {
    String[] arr1 = version1.split("\\.");
    String[] arr2 = version2.split("\\.");

    try {

        int i = 0;
        while (i < arr1.length || i < arr2.length) {
            if (i < arr1.length && i < arr2.length) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]) < Integer.parseInt(arr2[i])) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]) > Integer.parseInt(arr2[i])) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]) == Integer.parseInt(arr2[i])) {
                    int result = specialCompare(version1, version2);
                    if (result != 0) {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            } else if (i < arr1.length) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]) != 0) {
                    return 1;
                }
            } else if (i < arr2.length) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(arr2[i]) != 0) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }

            i++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}

public static int specialCompare(String str1, String str2) {
    String[] arr1 = str1.split("\\.");
    String[] arr2 = str2.split("\\.");
    for (int i = 1; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]) != 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 1; j < arr2.length; j++) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(arr2[j]) != 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if (arr1.length < arr2.length) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}


// test
public static List<String> getLowerList(String str, Comparator<String> comparator, List<String> list) {
    if (str == null) {
        return list;
    }
    List<String> newlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    newlist.add(str);
    newlist.addAll(list);
    // sort
    Collections.sort(newlist, comparator);
    // search
    int endIndex = Collections.binarySearch(newlist, str);
    if (endIndex >= 0) {
        // sublist 0 1
        return newlist.subList(0, endIndex + 1);
    } else {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> test1 = Arrays.asList(new String[]{
            "2.1.1", "1.21.22", "1.21.25", "1.113", "0.0.0.1",
            "2.0.0", "1.2", "2.0", "0.1", "1.2.1", "1.1.1",
            "11", "100", "" + Integer.MAX_VALUE + ".1", "",
            "2.0", "10.1"});

    List<String> test2 = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"", null, "0", "10.20.100", "3.1.1", "9.8", "10.3.92"});

    List<String> newlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    newlist.addAll(test1);
    newlist.addAll(test2);

    Collections.sort(newlist, new VersionComparator());

    VersionComparator compareVersion = new VersionComparator();
    System.out.println(newlist);

    System.out.println(getLowerList("2", compareVersion, newlist));
    System.out.println(getLowerList("3", compareVersion, newlist));
    System.out.println(getLowerList("4", compareVersion, newlist));
    System.out.println(getLowerList("5", compareVersion, newlist));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution with **null** and **blank** check

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class AppVersionComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    private final String delimiterRegex;

    public AppVersionComparator() {
        delimiterRegex = "\\.";
    }

    public AppVersionComparator(String delimiterRegex) {
        this.delimiterRegex = delimiterRegex;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String s, String t1) {
        if (!isNullOrBlank(s) && isNullOrBlank(t1)) return 1;
        if (isNullOrBlank(s) && !isNullOrBlank(t1)) return -1;
        if (isNullOrBlank(s) && isNullOrBlank(t1)) return 0;

        final var sourceSplit = Arrays.stream(s.split(delimiterRegex)).map(Long::valueOf).toList();
        final var targetSplit = Arrays.stream(t1.split(delimiterRegex)).map(Long::valueOf).toList();

        var i = 0;
        while (i <= sourceSplit.size() || i <= targetSplit.size()) {
            var sourceValue = getOrZero(sourceSplit, i);
            var targetValue = getOrZero(targetSplit, i);
            
            if (sourceValue > targetValue) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (sourceValue < targetValue) {
                return -1;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private Long getOrZero(List<Long> list, Integer i) {
        if (i >= 0 && i < list.size()) {
            return list.get(i);
        }
        return 0L;
    }

    private boolean isNullOrBlank(String s) {
        return s == null || s.isBlank();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way (in Kotlin, should work in any language though):

```
listOf(
  "0",
  "2",
  "0.0",
  "0.1",
  "1.2",
  "1.113",
  "2.0",
  "0.0.0",
  "1.1.1",
  "1.2.1",
  "2.0.0",
  "12.1.0",
  "11.0.1",
  "0.0.0.1"
)
.sortedBy {
    it.split(".").map { it.padStart(10, '0') }.joinToString(".")
}
```

Result is:

```
0
0.0
0.0.0
0.0.0.1
0.1
1.1.1
1.2
1.2.1
1.113
2
2.0
2.0.0
11.0.1
12.1.0
```

I have to admit it's a bit dirty but for me it does the trick and it is very short. Limitation: the version parts should not have more than 10 digits, but you can increase the padding for your needs.